# Comparing Two Date control and Time Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to compare 2 dates and 2-time controls in Asp.net web form C#.
EX:Journey start Date should be less than or equal Reaching Date. If reaching date is same as start date then journey start time should be less than journey end time, I'm using 12 hours time format. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have journeyStart date in journeyStartDate variable and reaching date in reachingDate variable.
so this will give integer value after comparing two date

```
int result = DateTime.Compare(journeyStartDate ,reachingDate);
if(result < 0)
Console.WriteLine("journeyStartDate is less than reaching date");
else if(result == 0)
Console.WriteLine("Both dates are same");
else if(result > 0)
Console.WriteLine("reachingDate is greater than journeyStart date");
```